# How to compare/test two datasets which are not supposed to be exactly equal

Tags: dataset, method-comparison

Example of such dataset is open, high, low, close, volume data of any stock over the period of last 5 days. This data is available at the frequency of each minute. I want to test the quality of my data against some other source (say yahoo finance). As this a one minute roll over data, it is not expected to match exactly with the other source. It is expected to follow the same price range and movement.

What are the most suitable tests that can predict and summary data quality of such datasets? Sorry for not being specific. I am not looking for exact solution, I am looking for advises which statistics tests can best suite such use cases.

Edit - Below are the sample data from both sources. There are minor differences in prices, which is acceptable as it is one minute rolled over data. But a value of 210p should not be acceptable.

[image]

One way is to get the percentage change of respective fields and find the standard deviation and mark it failed if it crosses a threshold standard deviation. But it won't work with volume field as any single bulk deal can cause a huge difference in data. I am completely new to statistics so just want to know if there are any standard tests which can be applied to such use cases. Desired output is summary of comparison with decision whether comparison has passed or failed based on a threshold value.

Comment: The process must begin by supplying a clear, quantitative definition of what you might mean by "quality."  Please explain.

Comment: Thanks. I have added further details to my question.